# how to verify only one text(font) on webpage selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Python**
Here i am trying to verify only one text (single font) on webpage.
this is my testing line: "+FCIN:~|210920145516|1|0|0000,0000|~"
i have to verify here |0|is there are not, because in my project some time it shows |1| also.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import openpyxl
import asserts
import unittest_assertions
import requests
import replace

import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
web = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
web.maximize_window()

excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\Sagar\Documents\validation.xlsx", data_only=True)
sheet = excel_document["Sheet1"]


for i in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
    url = "http://ts.vcccms.in/GwaliorMeterAPI/api/DeviceSchedule/DeviceScheduleInfo?DeviceID=2|"
    id = "A" + (str(i))
    cell_value = sheet[id].value
    web.get(url+str(cell_value))
    time.sleep(2)

    element = web.find_element_by_tag_name("pre")
    #"+FCIN:~|210928120957|1|0|0000,0000|~"
    if element.text != "+FCIN:~|210920145516|1|0|0000,0000|~":
        #print(element[1:10])
        print("Verify Failed: element text is not %r" % element.text)
        #print("Verify Failed: element text is not %r" % element.text)
        #web.back()

    web.back()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by **in** keyword in `python` :

**Sample code :**

```
element = web.find_element_by_tag_name("pre")
if "|0|" in element.text:
    print("|0| is present, Test should be passed")
else:
    print("|0| is not present, Test should be failed")
```

**“in” Keyword:**

- To check if a value is present in a list, tuple, range, string, etc.
- To iterate through a sequence in a for loop.

See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-in-keyword/) for more.